# SIGBART NSInternalInconsistencyException attempting transition while transition in progress

Tags: xcode, animation, transition, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm extending [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/) (a stand alone class that presents an UIAlertView to the user to solicit a rating for your app) by adding a single button that when selected will dismiss the alert, and bring up MFMailComposerViewController so the user can email feedback.

My implementation was/is to post a notification in Appirater, and then using [self presentModalViewController: vc animated: YES] from a viewController that listens for the notification.  That viewController is the super class of all my main viewControllers.

It works in one of the main viewControllers is up, but crash's from within other viewControllers are the current viewController and I see the following warning in the console:

> 2010-12-17 11:27:59.632
>   Wine.com[18514:207] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Attempting to begin a modal
>   transition from  to
>    while a transition is
>   already in progress. Wait for
>   viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know
>   the current transition has completed'

I tried delaying the sending of the notification from Appirater, but that does not seem to help.

Ideas/pointers?

Comment: thanks, but I was not looking for an opinion.  The user can say no thanks and it never shows again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when clicking on a `UIButton` to open a `Modal View`. I changed the `UIButton's` listener from `UIControlEventAllEvents` to `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. Basically, it was firing the Modal View on `Touch Down Inside` and then trying to create another instance of the `Modal View` on `Touch Up Inside`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that by implementing this in a superclass, I needed to make sure only the currently active viewController was processing the notification, not ALL 5 of them.